# jQueryRotate plugin in IE 7

Tags: jquery

i am trying to make the image slider in this tutorial 
http://usejquery.com/posts/create-a-unique-gallery-by-using-z-index-and-jquery, and i am trying to create the image rotation effect using the JQueryRotate plugin, it works fine in every browser except IE 7 in which the images ignore the z-index which works fine if i removes the Rotate function
here is my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/syaa3/4/

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use jQueryRotate ver.3 that is here

https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk

Maybe it will fix ur problem ?